# Tango Client API NDK static library for prebuilt

Tags: android-ndk, google-project-tango, ndk-build

So when you go to the official [Google Tango SDK Download page](https://developers.google.com/tango/downloads) you will find the Client API comes with both the header file and a `.so` library for both ARM v7 and v8 but in the Google Sample repo they have this [static library file](https://github.com/googlesamples/tango-examples-c/blob/master/tango_client_api/lib/libtango_client_stub.a) which if not included in my current Android.mk file will not build. Am I able to build the Client API without needing that static file?

Note: I am trying to build it as a prebuilt going off the [sample makefile](https://github.com/googlesamples/tango-examples-c/blob/master/tango_client_api/Android.mk).

Answer (score 1):

The static library `libtango_client_stub.a` is a clumsy attempt to resolve the limitation of modern NDK. On the face of it, you don't need this dummy library, but it is referenced in an imported `Android.mk` (via `$(call import-module,tango_client_api)`). If you use this `Android.mk`, you need the libraries in `tango_client_api/libs`, including the `libtango_client_stub.a`.

The bottom line is, you need the shared library `tango_client_api/lib/armeabi-v7a` for linking, but should not have its copy in your APK: this library should be preinstalled on your Tango device (see https://developers.google.com/tango/release-notes#unity_sdk_changes_15).